# Yelp return 200 but error using $http

Tags: angularjs, http, oauth, yelp

Yelp is returning status 200 with a JSON with results, but error callback is called. Maybe the JSON is malformed? I don't think so. But I cannot understand what is happening.

This is the code (angularjs):

```
$http.jsonp('https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=San+Francisco', {
    params: params, //All oauth params are correctly filled
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).success(function(data){
    deferred.resolve(data);
})
.error(function(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: See the note in the doc related to the url: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Comment: Can't set headers for jsonp requests. Also must have `callback` in params with specific callback name as per docs

Comment: Thanks! that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

callback parameter was missing in params. In my example, I have added callback: 'angular.callbacks._' + index

where index starts at 0 and must be incremented each time I make a call